# can @ConfigurationProperties annotated class auto refresh?

Tags: spring-boot

Can `@ConfigurationProperties annotated class` be auto refreshed when a value is changed in `application.properties` ?

Or do we have to restart to make the new value apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: "no". There is no general way to know if a change in application.properties requires a restart (e.g. a TCP port change) or not. If you know that a change will not require a restart then you can rebind the configuration properties using the `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` (or the public API of `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor`).